# Same rule for different directory in makefile

Tags: makefile

I am having rule like this.

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.s: %.c
    $(CC) $(PPE-CFLAGS) $(DEFS) -S -o $@ $<
```

i have a list like

```
dirs := $(OBJDIR) $(COMOBJDIR)
```

So, instead of writing duplicate code for each dir, can I make them into one? Something like iteration on demand?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your problem is unclear.
See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
post the problem  makefile. If it is big and complicated then
post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of a makefile that you want to make simpler. Please format
code by indenting it 4 spaces or using the code-formatting button in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

You have hit one of the weak spots in Make: its inability to handle multiple wildcards at once. There is a way, but it's ugly.

First take your rule:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.s: %.c
    $(CC) $(PPE-CFLAGS) $(DEFS) -S -o $@ $<
```

and put it into a variable, escaping the '$' symbols and replacing `$(OBJDIR)` with `$(1)`:

```
define myrule
$(1)/%.s: %.c
    $$(CC) $$(PPE-CFLAGS) $$(DEFS) -S -o $$@ $$<
endef
```

Then you can call it using `call` and invoke it using `eval`:

```
$(eval $(call myrule, $(OBJDIR))
```

That's good enough for `OBJDIR`, but to do the same for a list of directories, use `foreach`:

```
$(foreach dir, $(OBJDIR) $(COMOBJDIR), $(eval $(call myrule, $(dir))))
```

Or just use your variable:

```
dirs := $(OBJDIR) $(COMOBJDIR)
$(foreach dir, $(dirs), $(eval $(call myrule, $(dir))))
```

Ugly, but effective.

Comment: I still prefer to move the command into a (canned) variable, and then simply define multiple per-directory rules. More writing, but no sticky mess with quoting the `$` characters.